# google chrome keeps on loading my site

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I'm making my personal website using a lot of jquery and the basic HTML5/CSS3. I just put some `$(document).ready()`, maybe that's where the issue comes from..

As I'm trying to see how browsers deal with it, I figured out that google chrome keeps on loading (something but what?) the page. I mean the wheel is spinning in the tab panel and at the bottom of the page, I have a bar saying "Waiting for localhost...". I don't have this issue with Internet Explorer for instance.

How can I find where the problem comes from? Is it just a bad interpretation of chrome? The bar at the bottom is actually quite annoying...

Comment: Please show us your code, or at least some parts you think the problem may be originating from.

Comment: You're able to check what's happening when you open Chrome developer tools and look at the output in the network tab. There it's displayed what the browser is loading and with which results.

Comment: I know! I looked it up and all the 21 requests are transfered in 231ms, nothing special...

Comment: 1) Is this only happening on your site or on other sites as well and 2) have you tried if disabling add-ons solves this issue?

Comment: It only happens on this specific page (not on the rest of my localhost) and I don't have any add-ons..

Comment: I can also say that it doesn't happen with mac version of google chrome... So weird

Answer (score 0):

I've been through this:

Try to load the page in anonymous mode (⇧+⌘+N) - if there is no spinning
I would bet on an network activity caused by an extension - check the list (chrome://extensions/) and try to disable a few